# SQL count(), trying to count rows from two tables and restrict info displayed

Tags: sql, database, count

I am setting up a database that has a limit to the amount of people that can register for a course. In my course table I have a Maximum column which holds an int and in my registered table it holds all the registered people for that course. SO my web page should only display course times where the number of registered people in the registered table < maximum allowed in the course table. Heres my current query.

```
SELECT course.time,COUNT(registered.time),registered.maximum FROM course 
JOIN  (registered) 
ON course.type = 'computing' OR 
(registered.type = 'computing' AND course.time = registered.time) 
GROUP BY course.time 
HAVING COUNT(registered.time) < course.maximum
```

The problem with this is it counts all the registered people regardless of the course time, so if there is 2 people registered for different times it still counts 2 people registered for each time.

Hope I explained it ok and hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear to me why you have `registered.maximum` and `course.maximum`. And it would be easier to answer the question if we knew the actual table structure, rather than having to guess based on your code. But here goes:

```
SELECT course.time, COUNT(registered.time), registered.maximum 
FROM course 
  JOIN  registered 
    ON course.type = registered.type 
    AND course.time = registered.time
WHERE course.type = 'computing'
GROUP BY course.time, registered.maximum 
HAVING COUNT(registered.time) < course.maximum
```

I also did a group by on `registered.maximum`, because you will get a syntax error otherwise.

Finally, I changed the join to be on the type, and then added it to the WHERE clause. To me, that always makes more sense, though it may sometimes be slower. From my perspective, the JOIN clause is just for joining, while the WHERE clause is for filtering.

UPDATE: to also get courses with no one registered:

```
SELECT course.time, COUNT(registered.time), course.maximum 
FROM course 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  registered 
    ON course.type = registered.type 
    AND course.time = registered.time
WHERE course.type = 'computing'
GROUP BY course.time, course.maximum 
HAVING COUNT(registered.time) < course.maximum
```

Comment: sorry my mistake about registered.maximum, should read course.maximum. I just wrote the query and it still does not display the available slots if no one has registered for it. The table lay out is in Course:  fields are time / type / maximum and in registered: fields are type / time

Comment: That is a different problem though, right? In order to get courses which no one has signed up for, you need an outer join. I will add that to my answer.